# How to correctly inject a [jump + address] instruction into another process (code injection)?

Tags: c++, byte-code, injection

I am trying to inject a jump instruction into another process (External injection), although the injection operation has been completed the address was not correct.

**For example:**

```
unsigned int addr = 0x0048DA03;
unsigned int jumpToAddr = 0x0048D9B2;
unsigned char command[] = { 0xEA };
WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, (void*)addr, (void*)command, sizeof(command), NULL); // this line for jmp
WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, (void*)addr, (void*)jumpToAddr, sizeof(jumpToAddr), NULL); // this line for the address
```

**The result:**

[image]

As you see, after executing that code, the jump address is wrong.

Also, the same problem occurs with the following code:

```
void* reservedMemAddress = VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, NULL, 100, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
if (reservedMemAddress) {
    WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, (void*)addr, (void*)command, sizeof(command), NULL);
    WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, (void*)addr, (void*)reservedMemAddress, sizeof(reservedMemAddress), NULL);
}
```

1. **How can I write the address correctly?**
2. **How can I merge the two `WriteProcessMemory` lines into one to
   write the entire instruction ex:`JMP 0x0048D9B2`?**

Comment: `EA` is the `seg:off` jump. You really want to use this one and not `EB` with relative offset? Also the writes seems to use the same address of the write?

Comment: @PawełŁukasik: I want you to instruct me on the correct way to apply what I said before, injecting (ex: `JMP 0x0048D9B2`).

Comment: I think that if you look at what is written in the address ``addr`` you might understand what is wrong

Comment: @gipi: You might see something I don't. Please clarify.